# NSLocalizedString with variables Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to figure out how to use NSLocalizedString with variables.

For example, if I want to output "by Peter and Larry", in my `Localizable.strings` file, should I have the following?

```
"account.by_user" = "by %@ and %@";
```

How would I call `NSLocalizedString("account.by_user", comment: "")` with if there are 2 variables `name1` and `name2` where `name1` = Peter and `name2` = Larry?

Comment: This is a [very good article](https://medium.com/@mendibarouk/enhance-your-localized-capabilities-on-your-ios-applications-d3ba17138077) about localization in Swift for a robust architecture

Answer (score 46):

yes, you should have `"account.by_user" = "by %@ and %@";` and take this:

```
let localizedString = NSLocalizedString("account.by_user", comment: "any comment")
let wantedString = String(format: localizedString, "Peter","Larry")
```

Comment: What if i already have two separate localized strings "days" and "weeks" but i need to print "days X weeks" what is the solution for it

Comment: @j.krissa just join the localized string.

Answer (score 25):

This is another way and how I do it.

```
let myString = String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("by %@ and %@", comment: "yourComment"), name1, name2)
```

basically, the main idea of Localized String with format is like this:

```
let math = "Math"
let science = "Science"
String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("I love %@ and %@", comment: "loved Subjects"), math, science)
```

> **Note** that `localizedStringWithFormat` sets the returned String's `local` based on given first argument:
>
> - No, it does not translate anything.
> - This confusion comes from wrong naming of `NSLocalizedString`.
> - It should have been named `NSTranslatedString`, or `NSTranslatable` (instead of `NSLocalizedString`).

Comment: ‘%@‘ is a placeholder for a any value (*constant math & science) which is not being translated but put after, hence the use of ‘String.localizedStringWithFormat’.

Comment: If you check this Apple Documentation, https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html then go to 'Handling Noun Plurals and Units of Measurement', you will see that my way is the same as the Apple Documentation. They use %d in keys. If you're saying that Apple documentation is less correct, I won't argue. Anyway, in programming, there are a lot of ways of solving a problem. If that works for you, that works for you. Feel free to use it. I just offered my way of doing, which coincides with Apple Documentation.

Comment: @user25 you need the outer "localizedStringWithFormat" to do the substitutions in current locale. Imagine, that you have "%f" in the string resulting from NSLocalizedString, and pass a number "3.14" to it. In some locales the decimal point is represented with dot "." and in others it is represented with comma ",". That's why Apple docs and also WWDC video mention exactly this way of doing it.

Answer (score 12):

Adding a small sample below as it took me some time to figure the Localizable.strings file formatting.

**Example of adding variables to localized string:**

In code:

```
let myVar: String = "My Var"

String(format: NSLocalizedString("translated_key %@",
      comment: "Comment"), myVar)
```

In Localizable.strings file:

```
"translated_key %@" = "My var is: %@";
```

Of course, the `%@` on the right side can be placed anywhere:

```
"translated_key %@" = "My var is: %@";
"translated_key %@" = "%@ is my var";
"translated_key %@" = "I use %@ as my var";
```

Also, `%@` can be replaced by `%d` for int or `%f` for a float.

Answer (score 11):

An example with the Localizable.strings file:

In Localizable.strings file:

```swift
localizable_text = "Title %@ (Code: %@)";
```

In Swift class:

```swift
let title = "Error"
let code = "123456"
let alertMessage = String(format: NSLocalizedString("localizable_text", comment: ""), title, code)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using extension for this.

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "\(self)_comment")
    }

    func localized(args: CVarArg...) -> String {
        return String(format: localized, arguments: args)
    }
}
```

For example

```
// Localizable.strings
// "account.by_user" = "by %@ and %@"

// How to use
account.by_user.localized(args: "arg_A", "arg_B")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String(format: NSLocalizedString("Pick_Only", comment: ""), sectionData.max)
```

In Localizable.strings:
"Pick_Only" = "Pick only %d";

Answer (score 0):

Note that while using `"account.by_user" = "by %@ and %@";` as you key works fine, it is often a good idea to use positional specifiers such as `%1$@`, `%2$@` for localized strings. The reason for that is that this allows to use a different order of variables for different languages. For this specific case from the question probably it does not matter, but in some cases in some languages it might be needed to use a different order of variables due to grammatical rules used in that language.

So for example instead of using `"account.by_user" = "by %@ and %@";` you could use in one strings file this: `"account.by_user" = "by %1$@ and %2$@";` and in strings file for a different language use this: `"account.by_user" = "by %2$@ and %1$@";` and then the code below:

```
    let text = NSLocalizedString("account.by_user", comment: "")
    print("text: \(String(format: simple, "Peter", "Larry"))")
```

would print: `text: by Peter and Larry` for the first language and for the second language it would print: `text: by Larry and Peter`.