# NSLocalizedString with variable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nslocalizedstring

How can I translate a string that has a variable in it like this:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("NEUEARTIKEL",comment:"Bitte gib einen neuen Artikel für \(titelArr[sender.tag]) an:"), message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
```

When I just translate the String normally like this in the localizable.string:

```
NEUEARTIKEL="Add an item to \(titelArr[sender.tag]):";
```

The alert will show (titelArr[sender.tag]) instead of its value.

This is probably very simple, but I`m new to swift an wasn't able to google something helpful! ;-)

Thanks for your help
//Seb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSLocalizedString with swift variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277626/nslocalizedstring-with-swift-variable)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSLocalizedString with variables Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684868/nslocalizedstring-with-variables-swift)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your localisable, you can't setup a custom text directly, you can only use text and format flags. So, in order to get your goal, you can do this:

```
NEUEARTIKEL="Add an item to %@:";
```

After that, get your title well-formatted using `NSString(format: <#NSString#>, <#args: CVarArgType#>...)`

```
let title = NSString(format: NSLocalizedString("NEUEARTIKEL", nil), titelArr[sender.tag])
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
```

Once that done, your localizable string will be formatted as you want.

Answer (score 6):

This is another way and how I do it.

```
let NEUEARTIKEL = "Add an item to %@:"
let alert = UIAlertController(title: String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString(NEUEARTIKEL, comment: "Bitte gib einen neuen Artikel für \(titelArr[sender.tag]) an:"), titelArr[sender.tag]), message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
```

basically, the main idea of Localized String with format is like this:

```
let math = "Math"
let science = "Science"
String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("I love %@ and %@", comment: "loved Subjects"), math, science)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let myString = String(format: NSLocalizedString("account.by_user", comment: "any comment"), "Peter","Larry")

let title = String(format:
            NSLocalizedString("account.user_count", comment: ""),
                           users.count.description)
```

You can find gist [here](https://gist.github.com/czars/b88f08f0bc5e43598fc91580c697dd22#file-localizedparameterstring-swift)